# Correlation between Trace, Log and Metrics in Opentelemetry using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, open-telemetry

Is there any way to correlate between Trace, Log and Metrics in Opentelemetry using .Net/C#

I am able to correlate between Trace and log using OpenTelemetry in .net and able to send the data to Elastic APM Server. Same trace id present in Trace and Logs. Is there any way to Correlate between Trace, Log and Metrics in Opentelemetry using .Net

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello, did you figure this out? Did you manage to get Exemplars working with .Net?

Answer (score 0):

A metric is an aggregation, so you can't map a trace to a metric.

There is a feature called [Exemplars](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/metrics/sdk/#exemplar) which can provide an example of a trace that is part of the data point. That means you can go from a metric datapoint to a trace, just not the other way.